# how can I clean letter from my data using gsub?

Tags: r, regex, replace

I have big data set. this data are letter and number together. I would like to remove all letter from the numbers.

```
marker g1 g2 g3
m1 0.2AA 0.7CC 0.2CC
m2 0.3TT 0.5GG 0.3TT
```

I used these command

```
data <- read.table(file.choose(), header=T)
a <- gsub("AA", "", data) # when i wanted to remove all AA
```

BUT when I opened a, i found all data are number without decimal and different number like

```
152 1265 120 1254
```

any help?
thanks in advance

Comment: Select and ctrl+k to post code.

Comment: `gsub` works on a vector (or matrix), not a data.frame (or list). Apply it to a particular vector `data$g1 <- gsub("AA", "", data$g1)` or use `lapply` to apply it to multiple: `data[] <- lapply(data, gsub, pattern = "AA", replacement = "")`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. You saved my time. your answer and time are highly appreciated

Comment: You have not precised: do you need to remove `AA` only in the first column, or anywhere?

Comment: What if there is `AAA`? Should that also be removed?

Comment: There is no AAA. I have AA or CC or TT or GG in my data. The job was done.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, this is can be an option.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(C1=replicate(3, paste0(round(runif(1), 2L), paste0(sample(LETTERS,2), collapse = ""))),
                 C2=replicate(3, paste0(round(runif(1), 2L), paste0(sample(LETTERS,2), collapse = ""))), 
                 C3=replicate(3, paste0(round(runif(1), 2L), paste0(sample(LETTERS,2), collapse = ""))))
       C1     C2     C3
1: 0.35TP 0.86DT  0.6DM
2: 0.52OG 0.39KJ 0.98CA
3: 0.27RT 0.62IR 0.28WJ
DT
DT[, lapply(.SD, function(x){gsub("[^\\.\\d]", "", x, perl = T) }), .SDcols=1:3]
     C1   C2   C3
1: 0.35 0.86  0.6
2: 0.52 0.39 0.98
3: 0.27 0.62 0.28
```

The regular expression will remove everything except for digits and the character ".", because you need the decimals.